# Are these all valid ways to drop one row in dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   df.drop(index, inplace=True)
   df.drop([index], inplace=True)
   df.drop(index=index, inplace=True)
```

I want to drop some rows while iterating. Are these 3 the same effect?

Comment: why do you need `iterrows`? if you have the index to drop?

Comment: The index is known when iterating.

Comment: In general, it's not a good practice to modify a list / data iteratively while looping the thing. Instead, collect all the indexes and drop once after the for loop.

Comment: What's the difference? @QuangHoang

Comment: because you are modifying the index as and when you are dropping the rows and the position changes in the loop. Its good to append as a list and then drop altogether

Comment: It's still working, but just not that good practice. or it will cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

(more a comment than an answer, but too long to put it in a comment:)

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html):

> **You should never modify something you are iterating over**. This is not
>   guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the
>   iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no
>   effect.